# Cannot view MicrophoneLevel and VolumeEvent session info using OpenTok

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I have set up a basic test page for OpenTok using API Key, Session and Token (for publisher). Is based on the [QuickStart](https://tokbox.com/opentok/quick-start/) with code added to track the [microphoneLevelChanged](https://tokbox.com/opentok/v1/libraries/client/js/reference/VolumeEvent.html#properties) event. Page code is [available here](https://gist.github.com/yellis/46b0b720d97916e686a4). The important lines are:

```
var apiKey = "API KEY HERE";
var sessionId = "SESSION ID HERE";
var token = "TOKEN HERE";

function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
    session.publish(publisher);
    subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
} 
function subscribeToStreams(streams) {
    for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
        var stream = streams[i];
        if (stream.connection.connectionId != session.connection.connectionId) {
            session.subscribe(stream);
        }
    }
}
function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
    subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
    TB.log("test log stream created: " + event);
}

var pubProps = { reportMicLevels: true };
var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, null, pubProps);
var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);
session.publish(publisher);

session.addEventListener("sessionConnected", sessionConnectedHandler);
session.addEventListener("streamCreated", streamCreatedHandler);
session.addEventListener("microphoneLevelChanged", microphoneLevelChangedHandler);
session.connect(apiKey, token);

function microphoneLevelChangedHandler(event) {
    TB.log("The microphone level for stream " + event.streamId + " is: " + event.volume);
}
```

I know that the logging works, as the logs show up from `streamCreatedHandler`. However, I am not getting any events logged in the `microphoneLevelChangedHandler` function. I have tried this with both one and two clients loading the pages (videos show up just fine).

What do I need to do to get the `microphoneLevelChanged` events to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTok's WebRTC js library does not have a microphoneLevelChanged event so there is nothing you can do, sorry.

Comment: That really is a shame... google hangout's style autofocus is sorely missed.